# Not able to install rainbow kit

Tags: ethereum, wallet-connect, rainbow-js

[Errors while installing rainbowkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6uGx.jpg)

How to resolve these errors and install the rainbow kit. I am facing these errors while trying to install the rainbow kit to integrate the wallet and react hooks.

npm install @rainbow-me/rainbowkit wagmi ethers
I have tried viem as well instead of ethers in the above command.

Answer (score 0):

the first step is to make sure your npm version is up to date. if not, please update it from nvm. the second step is to download it as follows.
`npm install module_name --legacy-peer-deps`
it will download the libraries that are compatible here. I hope this was useful.